# ASP.NET MVC, get and display data using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm begginer in ASP.NET MVC, so I have many problems. One of them is:
how can I get list of books selected user (based on e.g. userId) and display them in view?

```
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        this.States = new HashSet<State>();
        this.UserProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
    }

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string PublicationLanguage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        this.Books = new HashSet<Book>();
        this.webpages_Roles = new HashSet<webpages_Roles>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UniversityName { get; set; }
    public string UniversityAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Activated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Books are added like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddBook()
    {
        Book book = new Book();
        return View(book);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddBook(Book book)
    {
        book.UserProfiles.Add(_bookService.GetUserById(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)); // get currently logged in user
        _bookService.AddBook(book);
        return View("BookInfo", book);
    }
```

and _bookService.AddBook(book):

```
public void AddBook(Book book)
    {
        using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            ctx.Books.Add(book);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The problem may be trivial but I'm still learning and I would be grateful for help

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to make simple the structure. Just add `UserId` property to `Book` and remove virtual collections from both models. Then, using LINQ, collect data you want:

```
public List<Book> LoadBooksByUserId(int userId)
{
        using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            return ctx.Books.Where(e=>e.UserId == userId).ToList();
        }
}
```

And you can show data by watching this: [Basic CRUD Functionality with the Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Book-User relationship is many-to-many, since each object has a collection of another. If this is the case, you should also add the book created to the Books collection of the User. Something like this:

```
_bookService.GetUserById(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Books.Add(book);
```

in AddBook action. So you will have reference of all books for User. Then just make another method/action to return the books collection of user. For example:

```
public List<Book> LoadBooksByUser(int userId) 
{
    using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
    {
        return ctx.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserId = userId).Books.ToList();
    }
}
```